# Oracle - Disable masive updates

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is any way to disable massive updates/deletes (without where clause) in SQL Developer?

Mysql workbench has a similar tool that prevents a user run update statements without where clause. Is any similar tool in Oracle SQL developer?

Thanks

Comment: You want that only in *the* client (SQL Developer) or in the database (regardless of the client)?

Comment: You could have a look at [Oracle Resource Manager](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/performance/resource-manager-twp-133705.pdf) and see if that does what you need. It has nothing to do with SQL Developer specifically though.

Comment: I prefer do it only in sql developer (for some reasons). If is not posible maybe we can do it on server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

But you can limit the damage a user can unleash on your SGA/temp space/CPU by creating a resource consumer group ([Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dbrm.htm#ADMIN027))

It's best to control this sort of problem at the database/server level. If you build 'security' into the client, then you're in trouble as soon as they go and use another client, like SQL*Plus or one of the 100 other Oracle database clients out there.

If you have a database user that does this frequently, [use the READ privilege in 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/release_changes.htm#GUID-00745268-6964-4EE7-92FE-6B4B72931043) and higher. It allows you to grant ONLY the ability to ONLY do a SELECT.

Comment: Is any way to limit the maximum records afected in a update query? I need to prevent that a single user updates a complete table by error. There is no problem if i need to use a specific client (or grant any system privilege). Its only for precaution.

Comment: @Mickey basically the answer is 'no' - you can restrict ability to do UPDATES completely, or they can update as much as they want - whether that's 'too many' or not. Also, what if there where clause is 1=1? Or they think they have a good one but it effectively is always true for every row?

Comment: The clause 1=1 is not a problem. Normally the user should updates in some tables but in certain situations he forget the where clause.... I want to prevent that user writes “update table set field=123” and forgets where clause and do a massive update. If he write “where 1=1 “ it’s not a problem because he wrote it...